# Blocking incoming call in android

Tags: android

I want to block/unblock incoming call in my android app. 
I am able to do that using below code.

```
telephony = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
customPhoneListener = new PhoneCallStateListener(MainActivity.this, vSMS);
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, 
                         PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
                         PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

But problem is that when I click on start button call blocking service activated and then we go to home page call blocking is still in activate mode.(that's fine).
but when I open my app and press stop button then call doesn't unblock. 
it still blocked. 
why?
what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is call unblock function is work before you press the home button? Did you check this scenario?

Comment: Is it working as a service?

Comment: yes it is working before i press the home button

Comment: @vivek tiwari: I'm intrigued by this - does this stop all incoming calls to your phone programatically, or does it just stop the ringer from sounding?  I want to stop incoming calls so that my app isn't 'onPause'd when a call is received, but your solution seems to be very simple and elegant compared to almost every other post on SO about it.  What devices have you tested this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the telephone object using the activity context and the `customPhoneListener` I guess is defined as instance variable in your activity.

But when you close the activity (by going to home screen) and open it again, you have a new context so the stop button almost does nothing.

To resolve this you can try the following:

1- User application context

```
telephony = (TelephonyManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

2- Ensure that the listener object `customPhoneListener` is the same during the life cycle of your application *not* your activity. Try to make it `static` or define it in the `application class`